# MPI programming issue with MPI_Gather

Tags: mpi

I am trying to use MPI to sort digits, after sorting by the different processors I want to use MPI_Gather to collect and later print all the sorted numbers but this is not working. Any help will be appreciated. Below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <mpi.h> /* Include MPI's header file */ 

    /* The IncOrder function that is called by qsort is defined as follows */ 
    int IncOrder(const void *e1, const void *e2) 
    { 
      return (*((int *)e1) - *((int *)e2)); 
    } 
    void CompareSplit(int nlocal, int *elmnts, int *relmnts, int *wspace,  int keepsmall); 
//int IncOrder(const void *e1, const void *e2);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 
         int n;         /* The total number of elements to be sorted */ 
         int npes;      /* The total number of processes */ 
         int myrank;    /* The rank of the calling process */ 
             int nlocal;    /* The local number of elements, and the array that stores them */ 
         int *elmnts;   /* The array that stores the local elements */ 
             int *relmnts;  /* The array that stores the received elements */ 
         int oddrank;   /* The rank of the process during odd-phase communication */ 
         int evenrank;  /* The rank of the process during even-phase communication */ 
         int *wspace;   /* Working space during the compare-split operation */ 
         int i; 
         MPI_Status status; 

         /* Initialize MPI and get system information */ 
         MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
         MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &npes); 
         MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank); 

         n = 30000;//atoi(argv[1]); 
         nlocal = n/npes; /* Compute the number of elements to be stored locally. */ 

         /* Allocate memory for the various arrays */ 
         elmnts  = (int *)malloc(nlocal*sizeof(int)); 
         relmnts = (int *)malloc(nlocal*sizeof(int)); 
         wspace  = (int *)malloc(nlocal*sizeof(int)); 

         /* Fill-in the elmnts array with random elements */ 
         srand(time(NULL)); 
         for (i=0; i<nlocal; i++) {
              elmnts[i] = rand()%100+1; 
            printf("\n%d:",elmnts[i]); //print generated random numbers
        }

          /* Sort the local elements using the built-in quicksort routine */ 
              qsort(elmnts, nlocal, sizeof(int), IncOrder); 
                  /* Determine the rank of the processors that myrank needs to communicate during 
          * ics/ccc.gifthe */ 
          /* odd and even phases of the algorithm */ 
          if (myrank%2 == 0) { 
              oddrank  = myrank-1; 
              evenrank = myrank+1; 
          } else { 
              oddrank  = myrank+1; 
              evenrank = myrank-1; 
                                      } 

          /* Set the ranks of the processors at the end of the linear */ 
          if (oddrank == -1 || oddrank == npes) 
              oddrank = MPI_PROC_NULL; 
          if (evenrank == -1 || evenrank == npes) 
              evenrank = MPI_PROC_NULL; 

          /* Get into the main loop of the odd-even sorting algorithm */ 
          for (i=0; i<npes-1; i++) { 
              if (i%2 == 1) /* Odd phase */ 
                  MPI_Sendrecv(elmnts, nlocal, MPI_INT, oddrank, 1, relmnts, 
                  nlocal, MPI_INT, oddrank, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
              else /* Even phase */ 
                  MPI_Sendrecv(elmnts, nlocal, MPI_INT, evenrank, 1, relmnts, 
                  nlocal, MPI_INT, evenrank, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 

                  CompareSplit(nlocal, elmnts, relmnts, wspace, myrank < status.MPI_SOURCE); 
           } 

        MPI_Gather(elmnts,nlocal,MPI_INT,relmnts,nlocal,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);


        /* The master host display the sorted array */
        //int len = sizeof(elmnts)/sizeof(int);
        if(myrank == 0) {

            printf("\nSorted array :\n");
            int j;
            for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
            printf("relmnts[%d] = %d\n",j,relmnts[j]); 
        }

        printf("\n");
        //printf("sorted in %f s\n\n",((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        }


              free(elmnts); free(relmnts); free(wspace); 
          MPI_Finalize(); 
    } 

    /* This is the CompareSplit function */ 
    void CompareSplit(int nlocal, int *elmnts, int *relmnts, int *wspace,  int keepsmall){ 
        int i, j, k; 
            for (i=0; i<nlocal; i++) 
                wspace[i] = elmnts[i]; /* Copy the elmnts array into the wspace array */ 

            if (keepsmall) { /* Keep the nlocal smaller elements */ 
             for (i=j=k=0; k<nlocal; k++) { 
                if (j == nlocal || (i < nlocal && wspace[i] < relmnts[j])) 
                    elmnts[k] = wspace[i++]; 
                else 
                    elmnts[k] = relmnts[j++]; 
             } 
         } else { /* Keep the nlocal larger elements */ 
                for (i=k=nlocal-1, j=nlocal-1; k>=0; k--) { 
                  if (j == 0 || (i >= 0 && wspace[i] >= relmnts[j])) 
                      elmnts[k] = wspace[i--]; 
              else 
                  elmnts[k] = relmnts[j--]; 
            } 
         } 
    }
```

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: I generate the random number, and do the sorting but after sorting when I call the MPI_Gather() function I got a partial sorted list. E.g. I might have something like this

Sorted List: 34,35,36,40,1,2,3,10,41,42,43,44: I hope that is helpful.

Comment: I think Mark's answer is correct: you need some way to merge the individual pieces.  I just also noticed that `relmts` is too small: it should hold the entries from all processes, and only needs to be allocated at the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code you've gathered the separately-sorted sublists back onto one process into the array `relmnts` ?  And then printed them in order of occurrence. But I can't see where you've done anything about sorting `relmnts`.  (I often don't understand other people's code, so if I have misunderstood stop reading now.)

You seem to be hoping that the gather will mysteriously merge the sorted sub-lists into a sorted list for you.  It ain't going to happen !  You will need to merge the elements from the sorted sub-lists yourself, possibly after gathering them back to one process, or possibly doing some sort of 'cascading gather'.

By this I mean, suppose that you had 32 processes, and 32 sub-lists, then you would merge the sub-lists from process 1 and process 2 onto process 1, 3 and 4 onto 3, ..., 31 and 32 onto 31.  Then you would merge from process 1 and 3 onto 1, ....  After 5 steps you'd have the whole list merged, in sorted order, on process 1 (I'm a Fortran programmer, I start counting at 1, I should have written 'the process with rank 0' *etc*).

Incidentally, the example you put in your comment to your own question may be misleading: it sort of looks like you gathered 3 sub-lists each of 4 elements and rammed them together.  But there are no elements in sub-list 1 which are smaller than any of the elements in sub-list 2, that sort of thing.  How did that happen if the original list was unsorted ?

Comment: Thank your Mark for your answer, but I think what you are saying is already done in the CompareSplit function, what the CompareSplit does is to compare numbers from odd and even numbered processor since I am using odd even sorting method and move the higher number list to the higher number processor and keep the lower list in the  the lower number processor. So at the end you will have all the numbers sorted in order according to the processors. i.e. processor 0 will have the smallest numbers and so on to the last processor which will have the largest number. That's the way I thought about it.